# Placing of adverbs

Tags: adverbs

I am confused where to place the adverb certainly

> She **certainly** has gone up in my estimation since she told the manager what she thought of him.
>
> She has **certainly** gone up in my estimation since she told the manager what she thought of him.

I think both of the positions are correct.

Comment: Both forms are correct. Example: [*“This is a moment that the country needs her leadership, and she **certainly has** stepped up.”*](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/06/10/us/politics/karen-bass.html) *New York Times*  June 10, 2020

Comment: @Princesadh  Saying or implying only the second sentence is correct is incorrect. That was my point. But if you disagree, undelete your answer and defend it.